# OOP and User input as parameters?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question with OOP and best practice. I have only recently grasped OOP in Python. My query is with user input. Most of the examples online do not include it. Is the following code correct interms of OOP best practice or is it very messy with '   ' these as the parameters?

```
class Userinput(object):

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def askuser(self,call):
        self.call = str(input('Enter in a letter  '))
        print(self.call)


a = Userinput('Test')
a.askuser('')
```

Comment: Do you realize that neither `self.name` nor the `call` parameter are used in any way? Also, in python 3, `input` always returns a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Userinput` class is not providing any value, so just kill it.  Classes and OOP are not the only way to write good Python.  In your case, stick with a simple function.

Comment: How exactly would I change it to make it a more viable OOP?

Comment: You don't, that's my point.  Don't try to jam everything into OOP, it's a mistake.  It's simple procedural code, let it be simple.

Comment: Just keep practicing Python, and don't think about OOP yet. OOP can be misused and just make things more complicated than it needs to be. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) to be interesting, check it out.